# Receiving unfilled contact forms on email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

so in the last 2 months my website is online, i have been received 2 normal email from my contact form and like 30 empty unfilled form emails. I also use validator http://faireware.de/js/jquery.form-validation-and-hints.js.
The weird is that i don't get these empty for emails when i i.e. dont fill an form and press send. It happens automaticly somehow... a spam bots or something, could it be?

My HTML code is:

```
<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">

  <div class="field required">
    <p>Name<br>
    <input class="text verifyText hint" name="name" type="text" size="25" title="*Ihr Name..."></p>
  </div><!--/field--> 

  <div class="field required ">
    <p>E-Mail<br>
    <input class="email verifyMail hint " name="email" type="text" size="25" title="*Ihre E-Mail-Adresse..."></p>
    </div><!--/field-->

    <div class="field required ">
      <p>Nachricht<br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="50" cols="50" title="*Schreiben Sie Ihre Nachricht..." class="hint "></textarea></p>
    </div><!--/field-->
  <p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Senden"></p>
</form>
```

and my contactengine.php is:

```
<?php

$Subject = "Kontaktformular - FaireWare";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$EmailFrom = $Email;
$EmailTo = "info@faireware.de";

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n\n";
$Body .= "E-Mail: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n\n";
$Body .= "Nachricht: ";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $Email");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

And the empty email forms do come like this:

```
Name: 

E-Mail: 

Nachricht:
```

Does it do it automaticly and how can it surpass validation...? I don't know PHP and very little java, so does anyone have any idea where the problem could be?

Thank you!

Comment: if you directly hit contactengine.php  then blank email sent .Please add server side validation,add captcha in client side.

Comment: its validation issue, $validationOK true in default. where is the validation code??

Comment: You're not validating the fields, i.e whether the fields are empty or not before sending the mail. Make use of `empty()` function.

Comment: if page referesh or just submit the button with empty field u will get empty email..

Comment: When i fill all the fields and klick Send, i get an email right away. I don't get empty email when i klick Send when my fields are empty. At least not right away. It doesn't pass the validation at all. Is it possible if i klick Send with empty fields still send an email, even though just day after or later? Or those are spam bots or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, i have modified your code with basic server side validations.

```
<?
if(count($_POST) > 0)
{
    $Subject = "Kontaktformular - FaireWare";
    $Name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $Email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $Message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
    $EmailTo = "info@faireware.de";

    $validationOK = true;
    if(empty($Name) || empty($Email) || empty($Message)){
        $validationOK = false;
    }

    if (!$validationOK) {
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
      exit;
    }
    else
    {
        // prepare email body text
        $Body = "";
        $Body .= "Name: ";
        $Body .= $Name;
        $Body .= "\n\n";
        $Body .= "E-Mail: ";
        $Body .= $Email;
        $Body .= "\n\n";
        $Body .= "Nachricht: ";
        $Body .= "\n";
        $Body .= $Message;
        $Body .= "\n\n";
        $headers = 'From: $Email' . "\r\n";

        // send email 
        $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

        // redirect to success page 
        if ($success){
          print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.html\">";
        }
        else{
          print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**What i have changed?**

Add starting check if `$_POST` array not 0 and than add basic validation with `empty()`. `If` any one field empty email will not send `else` you will get the email.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this and i will let you know it i get more unfilled contact form emails. Sorry, i think i should have send link so you can see how it looks in real life: http://faireware.de/test/kontaktformular.html

Comment: After reading comment from @Android Gears I just now noticed if someone opens directly contactengine.php, it sends me an empty email. My guess is that no normal user would do that anyway. So are spam bot doing it?
With your code it doesn't, which is already great! :)

Comment: @drakal yes I knw it will work now if u fell this is the best answer than mark as accepted by click on the left green tick it will help to others in future

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your server-side code to unbreakable to avoid spam. Here is some suggestions.

1. [Google Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)
2. [Honeypot Technique](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/01/honeypot-technique-fast-easy-spam-prevention/)

Also do server side isset check.

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
 // Save the data or do the further processing
}
```

Suggestion: Do not depend on client side validations when developing secure applications.

Comment: Thank you for your help. At the monent i would rather not use Captcha. This is just a simple contact form for people to get in contact, and instead i get spam. If nothing else helps, i will do this. Thank you for the links.